# Splitting JSON data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, string, json, decode

I got this data from my server using JSON:

```
{
    ID = 198;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "06:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Devotional Hits";
}
{
    ID = 199;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "07:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Old Malayalam Hits";
    }
{
    ID = 200;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "08:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Malayalam New Hits";
}
{
    ID = 201;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "09:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Melody Songs";
}
{
    ID = 202;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "10:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Jayachandran Hits";
}
{
    ID = 203;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
   dtTime = "11:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Yesudas Hits";
 }
 {
    ID = 204;
    dtDate = "2012-03-14 00:00:00";
    dtTime = "12:00:00";
    iPublished = 1;
    sProgram = "Ilayaraja Hits";
  }
```

I need to split this data and store sProgram data into an array.. need help.

I need to split this format and I want `sProgram` and `dtTime` separately. What should I do for that. I'm a little bit confused about string formatting.

Comment: Your JSON is [invalid](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Neeraj Neeru I think you have given only a part of JSON. NO one can help you until you put your full JSON.

Comment: @AlexCoplan sorry, this is the first time i used json,, i can't understand why you said my json is invalid.. i used Stig Brautaset’s JSON library (version 2.2), is their any problem ?                         tanq for your feedback alex

Comment: @NeerajNeeru - There are lots of issues with it - you can't have separate entities like that - they need to be inside an array - e.g. wrap `[]` round the whole thing, and put commas between each dictionary. You'll also want to quote all your values, and used colons  instead of = ... I'll answer with the corrected JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using  < IOS 5, add [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) to your project

```
//in some.m file

#import JSON.h

// Lets say NSString *recievedValue contains your JSON response.

id jsonRep = [receivedValue jsonValue];
if([jsonRep isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
   // returned JSON Value has a array structure.
   NSArray *value = (NSArray *)jsonRep;
   //You can access values using objectAtIndex: method if you already know the Index of a value, in your case i think each array object is a NSDictionary
   if([[value objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
   {
     // returned JSON Value has a key value compliant structure.
     NSDictionary *dicValue = (NSDictionary *)[value objectAtIndex:0];
     //You can access values using objectForKey: method if you already know the key value, in your case it can be @"sProgram" for example
   }
}
else if([jsonRep isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
   // returned JSON Value has a key value compliant structure.
   NSDictionary *value = (NSDictionary *)jsonRep;
   //You can access values using objectForKey: method if you already know the key value, in your case it can be @"sProgram" for example
}
```

Comment: ,actually i reffered Stig Brautaset’s JSON library (version 2.2),

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid - I recommend that you use [this tool](http://jsonlint.com/) to check this before posting about a JSON-related issue in the future.

However, I have corrected your JSON and validated it - it should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 198,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "06:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Devotional Hits"
    },
    {
        "ID": 199,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "07:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Old Malayalam Hits"
    },
    {
        "ID": 200,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "08:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Malayalam New Hits"
    },
    {
        "ID": 201,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "09:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Melody Songs"
    },
    {
        "ID": 202,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "10:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Jayachandran Hits"
    },
    {
        "ID": 203,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "11:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Yesudas Hits"
    },
    {
        "ID": 204,
        "dtDate": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
        "dtTime": "12:00:00",
        "iPublished": 1,
        "sProgram": "Ilayaraja Hits"
    }
]
```

You can then use the [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) to parse it.

As you asked, here is how you can now obtain all the values of sProgram:

```
NSMutableArray *programs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *data = [json jsonValue];
for (NSDictionary *dict in data) {
    [programs addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"sProgram"]];
}
// programs now contains all the values of sProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i used Stig Brautaset’s JSON library (version 2.2)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[table reloadData];
NSMutableData *responseData;
   responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://ganamradio.com/smartphones/date.php"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[responseData setLength:0];
}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responseData appendData:data];
}



 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
//label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error   description]];
}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];




   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//[responseData release];

dict=[responseString JSONValue];

NSArray *Programs;
NSArray *Time;
Programs=[dict valueForKey:@"sProgram"];
Time=[dict valueForKey:@"dtTime"];

NSLog(@"......%@",Time);


}
```

so i got the program list in NSArray programs,, is their any problem using like this..?

Comment: This is the way, but it is always good to check what type of data is returned by JSONValue method, like i showed in my answer.